# Reading Chinese characters with scanf() and then prinf() results in garbled output

Tags: c, clion

i find when i use in Clion scanf() to enter Chinese,then use prinf() to output it，it’s  will be garbled.

```
#include"stdio.h"

int main(){
    printf("你好\n");
    char str[10];
    scanf("%s",str);
    printf("%s",str);
}
```

if I enter Chinese，it’s will be garbled.

```
你好
你好
��
```

if i enter English,it's ok

```
你好
hello
hello
```

Comment: I could not reproduce the issue. Could you verify that the file encodings are UTF-8?

Comment: If your editor and your terminal are using different [character encodings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) that could cause the problem. For example if your editor is in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) and your terminal is in [Big5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big5).

Comment: Are you on Windows? Are you using the Microsoft compiler?

Comment: @Schwern then it would be the other way around, printing string literals would not work but echoing the input would.